# Choosing the right type of plot for my pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have been confused because I don't know which type of plot I must choose.

I have a data frame with two columns suppose the first one is the id of a person and the second one the number of houses this person has. I just only want to know which type of plot I need to use.

According to the question:

You will rank the owners on a number of houses basis. So, the first owner will be the one that owns the largest number of houses (e.g. 14), the second owner will be the one with the second largest number of listings, etc. If there is a number of owners with the same number of houses, just add them in sequence. For instance, if there are 10 owners with one listing each, add them in the ranking with any order between them.

That is, a point (x,y) will mean that the  x -th highest owner host has  y  listings.

Any advise?

Comment: Do your homework by yourself man ..

Comment: @W-B I don't want the answer just what type of graph is

Comment: Depends on how you want to present, tried pie graph?

Answer (score 0):

Some example data:

```
import pandas as pd
import random as r
people = ["Person{}".format(x) for x in range(1,20)]
numbers = [r.randint(5,20) for x in range(1,20)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(people, numbers)), columns=['personId', 'numHouses'])
df = df.sort_values(by='numHouses')
```

Now some charts:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot,init_notebook_mode
import plotly.graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
iplot([go.Bar(x=df['personId'], y=df['numHouses'])])
```